# Replacing special characters in recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb

I have a CSV file with double quote marks(") in some filds. When I try to upload the data into a recordset I get a crash. I used the following code in VBA:

```
Dim rscsv As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cncsv As ADODB.Connection

Set cncsv = New ADODB.Connection

cncsv.ConnectionString = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq="C:\Test\";Extensions=csv"
cncsv.Open


Set rscsv = New ADODB.Recordset
rscsv.Open "select * from " & fileName, cncsv, adOpenStatic, _
adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

I get incorrect data in the recordset with an err "94: Invalid use of Null" in the line with "rscsv.Open "select * from ...". The data is trimmed in the field where is double quote and after it all fields are with Null value.

For example if I have the following CSV data

```
  1            2            3            4
AAAA         BB"BB          123          456
```

...after my code I get

```
  1            2            3            4
AAAA         BB           Null          Null
```

How can I upload the data with replaced option (i.e. something like this 
 Replace(' " ', ' ') )?

Comment: Not sure if this will be enough to fix your problem but, if you're trying to use replace, to target " , VBA requires you to double up on them to show one set. `""""` is seen as ". To show an empty string, however, is just two double quotes `""`, but using `vbNullString` is typically a little faster

Comment: @Brotato, could you provide me with an example of the code?

Comment: "I get a crash" is not a very useful description of the problem you're seeing.  Is there an error message/ On which line?

Comment: @Tim Williams, I get incorrect data in the recordset with an err "94: Invalid use of Null". The data is trimmed in the field where is double quote and after it all fields are with Null value.

Comment: @Kirill Sorry, I don't think I understood the question correctly; it seems as if I'm a little over my head here.

Answer (score 0):

While establishing the connection use FMT=delimited. Here is a quick example:

```
cncsv.ConnectionString = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);" & _ 
                         "Dbq=""C:\Test\"";Extensions=csv" & _
                         "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
cncsv.Open

Set rscsv = New ADODB.Recordset
rscsv.Open "SELECT * FROM " & fileName, cncsv, adOpenStatic, _
            adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Note: Needless to say but highlighting, HDR=YES if your csv file has headers else HDR=NO. If the above solution doesn't work then you might need to use [Schema.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017).

Attribution: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974559(v=msdn.10)) & [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/)